# Why is this combination used in this probability problem?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

A labor dispute has arisen concerning the distribution of 20 laborers to four different construction jobs. The first job (considered to be very undesirable) required 6 laborers; the second, third, and fourth utilized 4, 5, and 5 laborers, respectively. The disputing ethnic group contains four members.

What is the probability that: a.) an ethnic group member is assigned to each type of job? b.) no ethnic group member is assigned to a type 4 job?

So for part a, I simply did (16!/5!3!4!4!)/(20!/6!4!5!5!) since you have to assign one of the four members to each of the four jobs. But I'm stuck on part b.

I would assume that it wouldn't matter what the other jobs were , so I tried 4c0 and then multiplied it by (16!/5!4!0!3!) just so all four workers could be allocated elsewhere. However, the solution says that I should have done 4c0*16c5/(20!/6!4!5!5!). Can anybody reason why we have to use 16c5? This is kinda of confusing me.

Thanks!

Comment: Unstated assumption: there seem to be four members of the ethnic group?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, forgot to mention that. There are 4 members of the ethnic group.

Comment: Please edit the *question* so that it contains all the required information

Comment: The question has been fixed.

Comment: If no members of that ethnic group are assigned to the fourth job, you have to assign five of the other sixteen available workers to that job.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of confusion both in your answer, and that of the book (permutation or combination, choosing jobs for people or choosing people for jobs), and if you evaluate what the book has suggested, it is patently incorrect.

Answers for part 2 by two methods, suffices to simply consider the ethnic group :

- *using combinations*
  Only 15 slots are now available for the 4 people, thus $\dfrac{\binom{15}{4}}{\binom{20}{4}} = \dfrac{91}{323}$
- *using direct probabilities*
  $\dfrac{15}{20}\cdot\dfrac{14}{19}\cdot\dfrac{13}{18}\cdot\dfrac{12}{17} = \dfrac{91}{323}$

---

**Added**

You could solve part 1 also similarly

$\dfrac{\binom61\binom41\binom51\binom51}{\binom{20}{4}}\;\; or\;\; \dfrac6{20}\cdot\dfrac5{19}\cdot\dfrac4{18}\cdot\dfrac3{17}$